# JBoss 7.1.1 Cache-Control Header

Tags: http, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a web application running on `JBoss 7.1.1`, and all the web-responses are being forced to have the cache-control `no-cache` header turned on.

Where this is coming from and how I can override it?

Comment: I need more information: What have you tried so far? Are you using a simple Java Servlet or are you using a REST HTTP framework like Resteasy/Jax-rs? Or others...

Comment: I am using Resteasy for my web services, and I have tried setting the @Cache annotation, however these settings are just being appended to the "no-cache" setting.  For example, @Cache(max-age=30) results in a response header like Cache-Control = "no-cache max-age 30"